# Truffle project encounters "Error: Cannot find deployed address"

Tags: contract-development, truffle

I am a beginner and was trying to run a truffle project but encountered an error which I am unfamiliar with. I based it off [Testing contracts with truffle](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7775/testing-contracts-with-truffle)

To explain this is my folder structure.

[image]

In my app folder I have the contract C.sol and migrations.sol

[image]

In my test, I have this c.js file

[image]

In my truffle.js, this is what I have written

[image]

I ran testrpc and then tried to compile truffle and then truffle test but I got this error below saying it can't find the deployed address. What is the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because you didn't deploy the contracts.You need to provide file name in truffle.js file and then need to run the command `$ truffle build` to build the project. Here is the related documentation : http://truffleframework.com/docs/

Answer (score 2):

I find it's better do arrange tests so they don't attempt to work with deployed contracts. That could cause problems in the real world. I'm not 100% sure and don't have time to test, but I think Truffle will not work with the deployed contract as expected.

A lot changed from v2 to v3 so that tutorial may be a little outdated.

You can do something like this:

```
var c;

beforeEach(function() {
  return C.new() // deploy a new instance of C.sol before each test
  .then(function(newInstance) {
    c = newInstance;
  });
});

it("should ... 
    c.doFunction(arg1, arg2 ...) ...
```

You can do

```
$ truffle migrate
```

or if testrpc

```
$ truffle migrate --reset
```

when you want to deploy and truffle will help keep track of the deployed contracts with c.deployed(). Again, I don't think the migrated contracts mix with unit tests, for safety reasons.

Hope it helps.